# Plugin - Admin menu page broken url

Tags: plugins, admin-menu

I'm working on a plugin.I've created a new menu entry inside my `functions.php`. The basic idea will be to have a default menu which will be the parent of several, small and different plugins.

I have pretty much all in place, but I have an issue when I click on the plugin submenu entry.

The URL is broken, and instead of going to the right admin page

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my_page
```

it goes to a frontend page, which is not available and so it goes on 404.
The broken URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/my_page
```

As you can see, `admin.php?page=` is missing from the second entry.

I've investigated a bit and it looks like this is fixed if i initialize the menu from the plugin itself, rather than the `functions.php` file.

Some code to prove it:

**WORKING**

```
public function add_menu_item()
{
        $page_reports = add_menu_page(__('Menu Page', 'menu-page'), __('Menu Page', 'menu-page'), 'read', $this->parent->_token . '_settings', null, null, '2.1');
        add_submenu_page('menu-page', __('Report', 'menu-page'), __('Report', 'menu-page'), 'read', $this->parent->_token . '_REPORT', array($this, 'IncludePluginPage'));
}

public function IncludePluginPage()
{
    include("../includes/index.php");
}
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
public function add_menu_item()
{
        //$page_reports = add_menu_page(__('Menu Page', 'menu-page'), __('Menu Page', 'menu-page'), 'read', $this->parent->_token . '_settings', null, null, '2.1');
        add_submenu_page('menu-page', __('Report', 'menu-page'), __('Report', 'menu-page'), 'read', $this->parent->_token . '_REPORT', array($this, 'IncludePluginPage'));
}

public function IncludePluginPage()
{
    include("../includes/index.php");
}

// Code from functions.php to generate the menu entry

function custom_admin_menu(){
    add_menu_page('Menu Page', 'Menu Page', 'read', 'menu-page', null, null, '2.1');
}
```

In both cases, the menu is correctly displayed, but when the menu is initialized from `functions.php`, the submenu URL is broken.

What am I missing here?

Please feel free to ask for more code, I wasn't really sure what to add in here to be as much help as possible.

In case you're wondering, I started from this template here:
https://github.com/hlashbrooke/WordPress-Plugin-Template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu is generated by the function [`_wp_menu_output`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/menu-header.php). If you look at the place where the links are generated (currently lines 158-162 and 170-174) you see that the `admin.php?page=` part is omitted under certain circumstances. One of those is an empty `$menu_hook`.

The variable `menu_hook` is filled by a call to [`get_plugin_page_hook`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_page_hook/), which will return empty if no action is bound to the hook. This translates to: there is no callback function defined to generate the page.

Now let's look at the [hook order](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference): plugins are loaded before themes, so if you generate the submenu before the parent menu (which you do if you initialize the parent menu in the theme's `functions.php`) there might be a problem at line 190-192 of [`add_submenu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/): it might not be possible to bind an action to the hook at that point because the parent page is undefined.

Disclaimer: I analysed the code from the top of my head, so I may have made a mistake there.

Anyway, if you insist on initializing stuff from your `functions.php`, don't try to initialize the submenu in your plugin. Instead just define the function in your plugin and call it from the theme as well.